# Error in running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got this error

```
Could not find mysql2-0.3.13 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I tried to gem install mysql2 but without luck, it didn't fix it. I'm using wampp server and copied the libmysql.ddl to the bin folder of ruby. I also tried adding the path to the gem install just like this.

```
gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- ‘-with-mysql-lib=”C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\lib” -with-mysql-include=”C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\include”‘
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? THanks!

Comment: I assume, you not only did `gem install` etc., but also `bundle install`. If you run `bundle show mysql2` what do you have?

Comment: I did do bundle install but gets an error on mysql2. My bundle show mysql2 says Could not find gem .

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have mysql installed on your machine.
If you have an Ubuntu distribution, try:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

then try to install the gem again.

Comment: I'm using windows. Is wamp not enough?

Comment: mysql2 used to have issues on Windows systems... There might conflicts due to the version of MySql you have installed. I would check mysql2's github page https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2

Answer (score 0):

I installed mysql2 from sources like this

```
# i experienced some troubles with mysql2 0.3.13 installing
gem fetch mysql2 -v 0.3.12
gem install mysql2-0.3.12.gem  -- ' --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 5.5\include\mysql" --with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files (x86)\MariaDB 5.5\lib" '
```

But after each Gemfile updating and bundle install, bundler is installing precompiled version of mysql2 gem and it's very annoying. After manual removing precompiled gem rails app started successfully

P.S. You also need installed Ruby DevKit.